# Resource competition between threads in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

[From Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable#kotlin):

> At the beginning of the run() method, set the thread to use background
>   priority by calling Process.setThreadPriority() with
>   THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND. This approach reduces resource competition
>   between the Runnable object's thread and the UI thread.

And what does it mean - resource competition between the `Runnable` object's thread and the UI thread? Does it connected to CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: if you don't know what it means, don't worry about it. Setting the thread priority is something that normally doesn't matter.

If your are starting long-running resource intensive threads, at the same time expecting to have a snappy user interface, then maybe this is applicable. I'd point out though that's not typically the type of thing done by a mobile device.

That flag gives the framework a clue it should de-prioritize that thread with respect to access to resources. In other words, that thread may take longer to complete its work. I say may, because if the system isn't resource constrained then it'll make no difference.